# How did we go from Binary to something like Python?

Tags: formal-languages, history, python, binary

If there's one thing the pandemic has shown us its that High school Geometry did not save us. I am a high school math teacher and I understand my job and its usefulness only exist in a post scarcity economy. That being said, my Principal is making me teach computer science as an elective, a subject I never studied in college, I was a pure math major my minor was in finance and I got questions for you big brains. I re-enrolled into my old CUNY non matric to take some computer science courses to better service these kids.

I have a firm understanding of how binary works as an input for computers and I like to believe my students have one as well. Right now were exploring ASCII and representing alphabetic symbols using binary, but I myself don't know how computer scientists made the jump from 1's and 0's to something like python. If yall got the time and would like to help me understand that bridge I'm all ears. In the mean time I'll continue my research and do my best to show these kids something worth wild.

Comment: What do you mean by jump? Is it how the encoding works, how a program (a word), written with characters like `a,b,c...` and other symbols (I don't know exactly which alphabet Python uses) gets stored as a binary word?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_programming_languages

Comment: The longest way in the wrong direction starts with a first step.